# Why isn't my react script working when imported from another file, but works as expected when defined inline?

Tags: reactjs

So i tried to make a short static react app (if you can call it so) just to get in touch with react.

I started with a sinlge file implementation and everything works perfectly fine. **Hello React!** is being displayed in my browser window whether i just simply open a page in my browser or serve it on the local http-server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>React</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id = "root"> </div>
    <script type="text/babel">ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello React!</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Further i divided the code into index.html and index.js files and now only a white window is being displayed. My directory looks like this

static_react

|----index.html

|----index.js

the index.html file now looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>React</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id = "root"> </div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the index.js like this

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello React!</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

I expect the **Hello React!** being displayed the same way as in the first case.

I tried to separeate the files into html and js files as explained above and expected the result to be the same as in the inline case

Comment: Open console and check if there are any errors

Comment: looks like it is was Cross-Origin error, the request was blocked because the CORS-Request. So now it worked on the local http-server !!!! But it wasn't working yesterday, and was not throwing out any errors. You sir are a magician!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to @Konrad.

After checking the console i have got a Cross-Origin error.
After checking out this
 [CORS request not HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default)

> Unfortunately this had security implications, as noted in this advisory: CVE-2019-11730. Many browsers, including Firefox and Chrome, now treat all local files >as having opaque origins (by default). As a result, loading a local file with included >local resources will now result in CORS errors.

> Developers who need to perform local testing should now set up a local server. As all files are served from the same scheme and domain (localhost) they all have the same origin, and do not trigger cross-origin errors.

I restarted the http-server with 'http-server -c-1' command and also deleted some cache vie the console and everything seems to work now.